# SELECT no me hace la compación en consulta

Tags: php, pdo

tengo esta pequeña consulta y quisiera logra que si hay un monto de **2000bs en la fila  monto_trasvalores_actual** mande a recargar y no pueda insertar el registro porque no hay fondos para realizar recarga, pero no me funciona

```
<!-- proceso para registrar-->
<?php
if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){

$sql= "SELECT monto_trasvalores_actual FROM trasvalores WHERE monto_trasvalores_actual = :monto_trasvalores_actual LIMIT 1"; //Creamos la select
$check = $DB_con->prepare($sql); //Preparamos la SELECT, de ésta manera 
evitamos SQL Injection
$check->bindParam(':monto_trasvalores_actual', 
$_POST['monto_trasvalores_actual']);//Substituimos las variables de la 
SELECT
$check->execute();//Ejecutamos la consulta
$monto_trasvalores_actual = $check->fetchColumn();
if ($monto_trasvalores_actual)
 {
  if ($monto_trasvalores_actual >= 2000) 
  {
     $check->closeCursor();

     $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: trasvalores insuficiente Por favor Actualize el 
  monto!";

  }
  }else{
   echo "La consulta no obtuvo datos";
  }


  $sql = "SELECT cod_ticket FROM adelantos WHERE cod_ticket = :cod_ticket LIMIT 1"; //Creamos la select
  $check = $DB_con->prepare($sql); //Preparamos la SELECT, de ésta manera evitamos SQL Injection
  $check->bindParam(':cod_ticket', $_POST['cod_ticket']);//Substituimos las variables de la SELECT
  $check->execute();//Ejecutamos la consulta
  $contador = $check -> rowCount();//Esta función devuelve el número de resultados que ha devuelto la SELECT
  if ($contador > 0) {
  $check->closeCursor();

          $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: El Registro ya se Encuentra Insertado !";

  }

  else

  {

  $sql=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO adelantos (cod_ticket,monto,porcentaje,ganancia,total,id_puntos,fecha,hora,id_usuarios) VALUES (:cod_ticket,:monto,:porcentaje,:ganancia,:total,:id_puntos,:fecha,:hora,:id_usuarios)");
 $sql->bindParam(':cod_ticket', $_POST['cod_ticket']);
 $sql->bindParam(':monto', $_POST['monto']);
 $sql->bindParam(':porcentaje', $_POST['porcentaje']);
 $sql->bindParam(':ganancia', $_POST['ganancia']);
 $sql->bindParam(':total', $_POST['total']);
 $sql->bindParam(':id_puntos', $_POST['id_puntos']);
 $sql->bindParam(':fecha', $_POST['fecha']);
 $sql->bindParam(':hora', $_POST['hora']);
 $sql->bindParam(':id_usuarios', $_POST['id_usuarios']);
 $sql->execute();

      $successMSG ="¡ Bien Hecho: Registro Insertado Correctamente !";


    }
 }


 ?>
 <!-- fin proceso para registrar-->
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no funciona? Y que trae la variable $monto_trasvalores_actual ?¿

Comment: me sigue registrando cuando deberia de mostrar el mjs de que no hay fondos

Comment: Por eso mi pregunta en donde asignas el valor a la variable de tu if

Comment: en ningún lado, como tendría que ser entonces para que me haga la comparación

Comment: @yoclens a lo mejor no estoy entendiendo bien la lógica, pero el primer select selecciona el monto de una tabla en la cuál el campo monto es igual a tu variable monto. Es decir, de antemano tienes el monto y sabes si es o no mayor de 2000 sin necesidad de consultar la base de datos. Luego podrías comprobar primero el monto y luego hacer el resto?

Comment: es que eso es lo que se quiere que compare si hay fondos, ejemplo si tengo un fondo de 2000 y quiero hacer una recarga de 10000 no debería insertar me debería mandar a recargar fondos para poder recargar saldo

Comment: Ya, mi lógica dice que debería preguntar si el fondo es ≥ de la recarga y asociado a unid de usuario o algo, pero es posible que me falte información, luego si hay fondos haría el resto, sino no hago le mando a recargar.

Comment: puedes trasladar esto a una sala de chat para poder explicarte mejor

Comment: No me sale la opción en el formato que estoy :(

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62248/discussion-between-carmen-and-yoclens).

Comment: Deberías modificar la pregunta y agregar la descripción de tu código hay, de este modo evitaras que tengamos que analizar todo tu código para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No estás recuperando el valor del select, por ejemplo: `$monto_trasvalores_actual = $check->fetchColumn();` Debes colocarlo después del `execute`. También, en PDO no necesitas usar `rowCount()` para saber si hay datos, basta con que evalúes los mismos datos. Si no hay datos la variable `$monto_trasvalores_actual` adquirirá el valor `FALSE`.

```
$sql= "SELECT monto_trasvalores_actual 
       FROM trasvalores 
       WHERE monto_trasvalores_actual = :monto_trasvalores_actual LIMIT 1"; //Creamos la select
$check = $DB_con->prepare($sql); //Preparamos la SELECT, de ésta manera evitamos SQL Injection
$check->bindParam(':monto_trasvalores_actual', 
$_POST['monto_trasvalores_actual']);//Substituimos las variables de la SELECT
$check->execute();//Ejecutamos la consulta

$monto_trasvalores_actual = $check->fetchColumn();
// No necesario: $contador = $check -> rowCount();//Esta función devuelve el número de resultados que ha devuelto la SELECT
if ($monto_trasvalores_actual)
{
    if ($monto_trasvalores_actual >= 2000) 
    {
        $check->closeCursor();
        $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: trasvalores insuficiente Por favor Actualize el monto!";

    }

}else{

    $errMSG = "La consulta no obtuvo datos";

}
```

Comment: lo he colocado pero no me funciona igual sigue registrando ya tengo -6000 en la bd xd jejejej

Comment: dejame editar el cod completo a ver si puse algo malo

Comment: listo he subido el cod competo

Comment: ¿Por qué la condición del `WHERE` está basada en el mismo campo del `SELECT` y en el mismo valor que recuperas en el `$_POST`? Es algo raro eso. ¿No debería ser `WHERE id=:id` o algo así? De todos modos, ¿has verificado qué valor tiene: `$_POST['monto_trasvalores_actual']`?

Comment: NULL la consulta no obtuvo datos

Comment: Siempre que trabajes con consultas y no te funcionen, verifica que está recibiendo los valores que _crees_ estarle pasando. En este caso, para depurar, escribe una sql de prueba, algo así: `$valor= $_POST['monto_trasvalores_actual'];  $sql_test="SELECT monto_trasvalores_actual 
       FROM trasvalores 
       WHERE monto_trasvalores_actual = $valor LIMIT 1"; echo $sql_test; echo $valor;` Así verificas lo que hay. Si la consulta se escribe con datos en `$valor` pruébala en phpmyadmin directamente para ver si devuelve datos.

Comment: MySQL ha devuelto un conjunto de valores vacío (es decir: cero columnas)

Comment: Amigo @yoclens significa que tu consulta no está obteniendo datos, por tanto, la comparación `if ($monto_trasvalores_actual >= 2000) ` no se puede hacer. Como te decía, es extraño el criterio del `WHERE`. ¿La variable creada para obtener el valor de `$_POST['monto_trasvalores_actual']` tiene datos?

Comment: entonces dices que el where deberia ir asi $sql= "SELECT monto_trasvalores_actual FROM trasvalores WHERE id_trasvalores = :id_trasvalores LIMIT 1";

Comment: Algo así @yoclens ya que de otro modo tomará **cualquier** registro cuyo monto sea igual a ese monto.

Answer (score 0):

asi deberia quedar me funciona de maravillas xd

```
 $sql= "SELECT monto_trasvalores_actual FROM trasvalores WHERE id_usuarios = :id_usuarios LIMIT 1"; //Creamos la select
 $check = $DB_con->prepare($sql); //Preparamos la SELECT, de ésta manera evitamos SQL Injection
 $check->bindParam(':id_usuarios', $_POST['id_usuarios']);//Substituimos las variables de la SELECT
 $check->execute();//Ejecutamos la consulta
 $monto_trasvalores_actual = $check->fetchColumn();
 $monto=$_POST['monto'];

 if ($monto > $monto_trasvalores_actual){
 $check->closeCursor();


     $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: trasvalores insuficiente Por favor Actualize el monto!";

  }

 else 

  {
```

Comment: Amigo, en vez de una auto respuesta considero que es bueno valorar el esfuerzo que otros hacen por ayudar a resolver el problema. No lo digo porque se trate de mi. Hay ya una respuesta que ha corregido gran parte del código  y comentarios en ella que han conducido a determinar que había un problema en el `WHERE`

Comment: tienes toda la razón y estoy agradecido de usted por siempre dar consejos que son bien valorados en mi muchas gracias por tus aportes